# Yii2 GridView action column doesn't send post parameter

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to send simple post param through `Html:a()` element in my `GridView`. But the `id` doesn't reach the action. This is what I tried (seen in documentation):

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{update} {delete}',
    'buttons' => [
        'update' => function($url, $model){
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>', ['c-update', 'id' => $model->id], [
                'data' => [
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]);
        }
    ]
],
```

The method is `post` and in controller verbs the action `c-update` is set to receiving only `post` requests. `var_dump($_POST)` in the action is empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID is in `$_GET`. Second argument of `Html::a()` method is for generating URL, it does not define data for POST request. So you're sending empty (without data) POST request to `/my-controller/c-update?id=123` URL.

You can get this ID easily in your action:

```
public function actionCUpdate($id) {
    // ...
}
```

---

If you really want to send ID as POST data you should do something like:

```
Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>', ['c-update'], [
    'data' => [
        'method' => 'post',
        'params' => [
            'id' => $model->id,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

But you should probably not do this. It is easy to lose context whe you're sending ID of modified record as POST data (since for every record URL will be the same). Using GET params to identify requested resources is perfectly fine.